# Use only FB and Twitter Logo not their Functionality

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Is there any issues with using FB and twitter logos even though we aren't really using their functionality?
Apple can reject my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is guidelines of using [Facebook Brand](https://www.facebookbrand.com/guidelines?asset=2&media=1,2,3&platform=0), that describe what to `DO` and `DON'T`.

Make sure you follow all steps of facebookbrand.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the [Best practices to use facebook login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/best-practices)  and  [appcenter guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines) before using facebook sdk for login.
And as the accepted answer suggests you should not use only logo, may lead to app rejection.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you should not use the logo, if you dont have their functionality integrated, however you can mention their names instead of logo.

There are very few chances that apple can reject your app. But i would recommend not to use logo without functionality